# Hadoop Name node is not getting started

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I'm trying to configure Hadoop in fully distributed mode with 1 master and 1 slave as different nodes. I have attached a screenshot showing the status of my master and slave nodes.

In Master: 
**ubuntu@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes**

refreshNodes: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop-master/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "hadoop-master":8020;

This is the error I'm getting when I try to run the refresh nodes command. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or what mistake have I done ?

[Master & Slave Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3hxm.png)

> 2016-04-26 03:29:17,090 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for standby state
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,095 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50070
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,097 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
>       java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [hadoop-master:8020] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:721)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:425)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.(Server.java:574)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.(Server.java:2215)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.(RPC.java:938)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:534)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:509)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:783)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.(NameNodeRpcServer.java:344)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createRpcServer(NameNode.java:673)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:646)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:811)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:795)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1488)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
>       Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:408)
>           ... 13 more
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
>       2016-04-26 03:29:17,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>       /************************************************************
>       SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hadoop-master/127.0.0.1
>       ************************************************************/
>       ubuntu@hadoop-master:/usr/local/hadoop$

Answer (score 0):

DFS needs to be formatted. Just issue the following command ;

hadoop namenode -format

Or

hdfs namenode -format

Comment: I did it several times with both stop-dfs and start-dfs, but I had no improvement

Answer (score 0):

Check your namenode address in core-site.xml. Change to 50070 or 9000 and try

The default address of namenode web UI is http://localhost:50070/. You can open this address in your browser and check the namenode information.

The default address of namenode server is hdfs://localhost:8020/. You can connect to it to access HDFS by HDFS api. The is the real service address.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried both, but the namenode is not getting started. And if the Name node is not started then we cannot view the web UI rite.

Comment: Try clearing your hadoop directories and reformatting the namenode (dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir in master and slave)

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the Namenode.
$] hadoop namenode -format

Answer (score 0):

Your error logs clearly say that It is not able to bind the default port.

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [hadoop-master:8020] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

You need to change the default port to some port which is free.

Here is the list of ports given in [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) and [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/).

Comment: Thank you so much. My Name node is up and I can see the Web UI now.
 I have a new problem, No. of live nodes and data nodes is showing as 0. But when I ssh into my slave node and type 'jps' it shows as the data node process is running.